# product of two non-decomposible (closed) polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abstract-algebra

Let $C$ be the field of complex numbers. Polynomial $f \in K[x,y]$ is called closed or non-decomposible if 
$C[f]$ is algebraically closed (definition for $f \in K[x1,...,xn]$ is the same).

Theorem.
Next conditions are equivalent:
(1)  $f$ is closed;

(2)  there does not exist any $F \in K[t]$ such that $f = F(h)$ for some $h \in K[x,y]$;

(3)  $f + a$ is irreducible for all except finitely many $a \in C$.

(4)  there exist $a \in C$ such that $f + a$ is irreducible. (end of the theorem)

It is clear, if $f$ is irreducible then $f$ is closed.

It is easy to see that if $f$ and $g$ are irreducible, then $fg$ is closed.

Question: Assume $f$ and $g$ are closed. Is it true that $fg$ is closed?

Comment: You don't mean $C[f]$ is algebraically closed, just algebraically closed in $K[x,y]$, I hope. Similarly, (2) above, I hope you mean $\deg F>1$. Thirdly, it is not true that if $f,g$ are irreducible, then $fg$ is closed, since one can take $f=g=x$, but $x^2=fg$ is not closed.

Comment: If we take the definition of closed to be (2) with $\deg F > 1$, then we get counterexamples whenever $f$ is closed and $g=f$, since then $fg=F(f)$ with $F=t^2$.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to write that $f$ and $g$ are algebraically independent! But anyway, it is not true (and easy), an example is: $f=x^{2} y$, $g = y (x+y)^{2}$  and then $fg = (xy(x+y))^{2}$.

Comment: Mohan, yes, I mean $C[f]$ is algebraically closed in $C[f,g]$ (I mean $C=K$) and in $(2)$, of source (sorry, I did not write it),  I mean $deg F > 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned above in the comment, the answer to my question (very easy question) is negative!

P.S. Of course I meant that $f$ and $g$ are algebraically independent!